# How do you create a Linux ISO? (Debian fork)

Tags: debian-installer, debian-cd

I did see this question on other threads - but I'm going to be a bit more specific.

Let's say I would like to take the Debian base (stable) and then rename it and add some own repos (and packages). How do I then generate an ISO image properly? How do I modify the installer?

I just wan't to learn - not anything too professional.

Answer (score 1):

As for the installer, just use *Systemback* or a similar program for installing your "own" distribution. With a tool like this, you can copy your currently used system in its current state to for example a DVD. After you boot from this DVD it will be like your system, which has Systemback installed, which lets you once again install this very system onto any computer.

Read the tutorials on how to use the *Live system create* and *System install* features.

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I instead would like to use a repository instead of my very own system, do you know if that's possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Great question XD.

Comment: I more meant  like, how would I do it if it's wouldn't necessarily be based on the running system?

Comment: You mean you just want to apply a certain configuration to future distros? That's more tricky. Especially the newer the distros are and the older your configurations this might be already incompatible. And even if it is compatible, in theory, this doesn't mean it will work flawlessly too often, because every hardware setup is different and makes the whole system, including the OS running on it, different. So, in theory, if you have some stock pc from Dell on something, where this configuration works and you want to apply this configuration on more of the *same* PCs, then it'd work, I guess.

Comment: Well, maybe you should elaborate more what your actual goal is. Because maybe we could try a different (and better) approach to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well okay - I would like to make a fork of a distro with an installer. Like any Ubuntu fork for example, Linux Mint, ZorinOS, elementary etc. Just that I won't release it - just try out to learn stuff (with an installer, and this will be based on Debian instead). Hopefully that's a bit more specific.

Comment: @MrKaKisen Then use Systemback for it. Works flawlessly for your purpose.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you think systemback is used by other *real* distros?

Comment: @MrKaKisen I guess, we could talk about what *real* means, but I'll skip this for sake of the argument since I know what you mean by that. caine-live.net uses Systemback as its installer.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! I know Arch has something named mkarchiso, is there anything equivalent for Debian?

Comment: @MrKaKisen I don't know that, but I think a quick google search will find out.

Comment: Couldn't find anything exactly like it ;(. Thanks for answers anyway!